# How to wait for socket connect within rest request?

Tags: javascript, rest, sockets

(This is my first ever contact with Javascript. ...)

Hi, I have to write a rest api with Express, which is no problem due to the huge amount of examples everywhere.

Though, within a rest request I've to contact another tcp server (for modbus). So, within such a request I've to wait for the connect/ready event from socket.connect(). What's a proper way to do that?

What I came up with is encapsulating the socket.connect() in a Promise. The stripped code looks like:

```
function get_holding() {
    const socket = new net.Socket();
    const client = new modbus.client.TCP(socket); /* = require('jsmodbus') */

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // fulfill the Promise, proceed in the chain
        socket.on('ready', function () { resolve(); });

        // close connection after receiving the response
        socket.on('data', function () { socket.end(); });

        socket.on('error', function (error) { reject(error); });
        socket.connect(/* ip and port */);
    })
    .then(function () {
        // could be above in socket.on('ready', ...),
        // but splitting looks better
        return client.readHoldingRegisters(0, 2);
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        // process response (code stripped)
        return /* processed values */;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        throw error;
    });
}

function controller_get_holding(req, res) {
    get_holding()
        .then(function (values) {
            res.json(values);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            res.send(require('util').inspect(arguments, {depth: null}));
        });
}

...
app.route('/holding')
    .get(controller_get_holding);
```

Is that the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Just found [promise-socket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-socket), which is all I need.